# war, ejb-jar and persistence.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, war, packaging, persistence.xml

I have project with two ejb-jars located in [WAR]/WEB-INF/lib. Both ejb-jars uses JPA and contains classes annotated `@Entity`. But I have problems with packaging and deployment (Glassfish 4). If both of my jars contains persistence.xml then I get following Exception on delpoyment

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [...] in the scope of the module called [...]. Please verify your application.`

I've put `persistence.xml` in WAR/META-INF and delete `persistence.xml` from ejb-jars. Deployment is successful, but I get Exception in runtime

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT ...]. 
[14, 18] The abstract schema type 'MyClass' is unknown.`

`MyClass` is `@Entity` class from one of ejb-jars. I think problem is missing `persistence.xml` in this ejb-jar.

Finally I've try to put `persistence.xml` in WAR and in ejb-jars, but again I get

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [...] in the scope of the module called [...]. Please verify your application.`

What is a proper place to put `persistence.xml` and what is a proper way to package such application?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract all your entities from both ejb projects and persistence.xml to the simple jar file and put that jar file to WEB-INF/lib (I didin't used that config, so it might not work, for sure it would work in case of EAR packaging - meaning EAR, with 3 modules, web and 2 ejbs, and entity jar in ear/lib folder).

Comment: It works that way, when everything in one jar. I'm novice at Java EE, so it seems easier to me to put ejb-jars in [war]WEB-INF/lib. I don't have thorough understanding of packaging in ear. If I package in ear, then can I see classes from one ejb-jar inside another ejb-jar?